# Conditional Expression on multiple models

Tags: django, django-orm

**Background:**

My customer's shop has Internet wifi for customer and also his staff.
Shop owner would like to visualize the heatmap of his shop in order to arrange the desk and furniture for sake of convinient.

**Schema:**
https://gist.github.com/elcolie/7bb56c286afacadff63eccae94bda713

**Goal:**
1. I want to determine `mac` address to be a `pin_value`

**Constraints:**
1. One mac can has many `imc`(username). Public computer serves many customer
2. One `imc` can has many `pin_value`. Customer got promote his `pin`
3. `imc` does not need to has `pin_value`. Staff account has no `pin_value`
4. `mac` does not need to has `imc`. May be somebody their just passing by without turn off his wifi

**Question:**
How do you use conditional expression to do single query and get `mac:pin_value`?
My poor solution is brute-force search which is very slow.
Location model has record per day is about 100k rows.

Comment: I hope my post can be a good exercise for Django primer.